# Is there any way to generate ELF BINARY using only python library?

Tags: python, assembly, binary, elf

Is there any way to generate `ELF binary` using only the python library?

I want to assemble the file below using python library.

`a.s` :

```
line 1 : .global _start
line 2 : _start:
line 3 :  push _STRING1
line 4 :  push _STRING2
line 5 :  call printf
line 6 : _STRING1:
line 7 :  .string "gogo"
line 8 : _STRING2:
line 9 :  .string "%s"
```

I've tried to use two python libraries `keystone`, and `pwntool`.
However, they support only machine code byte emission corresponding to assembly command.
(It didn't generate `ELF binary` consisting of elf header, section header,.. etc)

Also, It doesn't support handling on external library info. (such as `line 5`)

Q. I wanna generate a complete ELF BINARY `a.out` using python library.
Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: Generally, you would simply invoke the assembler `as` from your Python program.  You can also check out the `libbfd` which is what all the GNU binutils use to handle ELF files.  See e.g. [here](https://pypi.org/project/pybfd/) for bindings.

Comment: Obviously you can emit the necessary headers and whatnot yourself. So it's clearly possible, just depends on how much work you care to invest :)

Comment: Assemble and link your assembly file into an ELF executable with a standard assembler and ELF linker. Convert the resulting ELF executable into base64 encodiing with the `base64` command. Cut & paste the base64 encoded executable into a Python string (eg. `elfexe_base64 = """<paste here>"""`). You can now generate that complete ELF executable with `file("a.out", "wb").write(elfexe_base64.encode("base64"))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to assemble the below file

Note that your program is *ill*-defined:

- You call `printf`, but you didn't allow C runtime to be initialized. (If you want to call any libc functions, you should let the `_start` to be defined in `crt0.o`, and your program should start at `main`, not `_start`).
- You don't properly terminate your program (don't call `exit`, `_exit`, or execute `SYS_exit` syscall). You can return from `main` (libc-provided `_start` will then execute `SYS_exit` for you), but you must *not* return from `_start`, and certainly not fall from the end of it to whatever code or data is immediately after it.

Back to your original question: it's possible to "hand-assemble" an ELF file -- data is data.

However, that's a *lot* of work (and pretty pointless work), so you are much better off simply invoking external assembler and linker.

Comment: glibc on Linux will initialize itself if linked dynamically.  There are other libc implementations (like MUSL) that never need init functions to be called, even from a statically-linked executable.  So the OP's code is dangerous, and not recommended, but point 1 isn't fundamentally broken.  Point 2 is, though!  (I think you meant to say you can simply `ret` from `main`, but as written the 2nd sentence looks like it's saying there's no way to exit from `_start`).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. Re-worded.

Answer (score 0):

I know of a powerful tool called  radare2 https://github.com/radare/radare2.
It also supports python bindings https://github.com/radare/radare2-bindings.

Radare can be used as an assembler https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/tools/rasm2/assemble.html. I haven't tested, but i think it could help you with the elf binaries.
But in general, what you are trying to do probably requires a lot of manual labor.